# How to trigger fancybox to open on webpage when clicked on from an email?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancy box for a youtube video pop up. The way it works now is there is a graphic that you click on to play the video which opens the fancy box pop up of the youtube video. It works fine, but my question is that I'm creating an html email that will be sent and it will have the same graphic of "click me to watch the video."

I want it to go to the web page and have the fancy box pop up of the video open when the user clicks on that graphic from the email.

Is there a way to set up the href of the link so it initiates fancy box to open and load the youtube video?

I don't want this fancy box pop up to be on page load of this page, I just want it to trigger open if you clicked on it from the email.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to put a special param in the url and trigger the fancybox in your javascript only if the param exists.

Link URL:

```
http://yoururl.com/#showfancybox
```

Javascript:

```
if(window.location.hash == '#showfancybox') {
  // trigger the fancybox
}
```